# Get content from XML document

Tags: php, xml, regex

Hi i'm trying to get parts on xml document to add them in my database but using php and regex could;n do that, please help me i have tried to search in google but nothing could use no benefit. 
This is example of XML code

http://www.games-flash-online.com/rss.php?r=category&id=15&l=10

I'm trying to get each title each link of file each src attribute of image  and description is there good solution for me ?

Comment: So you Googled "php parse xml" and found nothing useful? That is very hard to believe. Hold on....

Answer (score 0):

[simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) is your friend. You can parse the xml file and then loop over the tree. This page contains straightforward examples.